# I can't find the title to this book in my huge Amazon library

Tags: story-identification, urban-fantasy

HELP, I an looking for the title about a girl that witnessed the modern world end and now she works odd jobs and trades fish to help feed her 2 brothers and hateful mother. She is at the town celebration when she finds a flyer staying the army is looking for people with special powers which she hides to take behind the wall. She knows if she goes she'll never come back but is made to go when her family is threatened and discovers demons are working behind the wall, trying to close the portal to hell. She has feelings for the head demon and discovers the seals are being broke to stop her from closing the portal to hell for good. She and the group of demons are running out of time

Comment: Looks like your question could do with some more detail. What is the wall you are talking about? What powers does the girl have? Is she working with the group of demons? Why are they running out of time?

Comment: When did you read this, was it in English? Polish? Spanish? What did the cover look like? What did the demons look like? What was "the wall" where was the wall, North, south? Circling the last human city? Any detail might be important! Good luck, I hope you get a satisfactory actor